# How to detect and drop an idle connection with Fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

```
#import ssh
import socket
from fabric.operations import run

def connect_and_wait():
    #ssh.config.socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
    print('SSTART')
    run('echo START')
    run('sleep 10')
    run('echo END')
    print('EEND')
```

The script above prints everything without any error/exception.

Python 2.6.5, Fabric 1.4.2.

- `socket.setdefaulttimeout()` does not work.
- `ssh.config.socket.setdefaulttimeout()` does not work.
- `fabric.api.env['timeout']` is for connecting phase only I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric uses "lazy" connections to remote hosts and can automatically reconnect when executing task on a host and connection is lost. Seems there is no way to explicitly drop idling connections, but you can close all connections and let fabric reconnect to "active" hosts. `fabric.network.disconnect_all()` do the trick.

Comment: Just as a thing worth remembering: disconnect_all() is in all my code due to Cygwin bug: every run() after the first one is executed with Cygwin service owner's privileges.